# merging three arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

So, I have three arrays:

$foo

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sum] => 281
            [status] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sum] => 1534
            [status] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sum] => 1434
            [status] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [sum] => 2468
            [status] => 3
        )

)
```

$rock

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [sum] => 514
                [status] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [sum] => 500
                [status] => 1
            )

    )
```

$bar

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sum] => 458
            [status] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sum] => 500
            [status] => 1
        )

)
```

I need to merge `$bar` and `$rock` with `$foo`, such that the key sum is added.

for example:
on merging `$bar` and `$rock` with `$foo`, the first index, where `status` is 0 would look something like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [sum] => 1253 (281 + 514 + 458)
        [status] => 0
    )
```

And the merge should happen based on the `status`. `status` 0 from `$rock` would merge to `status` 0 of `$foo`

I was thinking if this is a recursion application and making things more complex.

How should I solve it in an easy and optimized manner?

Comment: Try turning them into a single array with [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php), then processing the whole thing as one array.

Comment: Is the status always equal to the array key/index?

Comment: @Scott No, status will not be equal to key/index.

Comment: Why not sort each array  by status and run through the arrays iteratively, summing over each status?

Comment: @JannisM: Not tried anything in particular. Just wanted to know what would be the correct way to do it. I am confused.

Comment: i would just do a lazy foreach loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am always a fan of general use functions that could be used in the future. This solution takes three arguments:

1) An array of all the arrays that need to be combined

2) The key which will be used as a basis of comparison (two nodes that have the key will be combined)

3) The data-key which will be the field that is combined if the nodes are 'equal'

Lastly, php is very good at making dictionaries/hashmaps. This will help when we combine arrays because we won't have to do much searching.

```
/**
 * $arrays - an array of arrays to be combined
 * $key - a key in the array that represents the key that holds the values that need to be compared 
 * $data - a key in the array that represens the key that holds the data
 */
function combine($arrays, $key, $data) {
$ans = array();

//Go through each array that needs to be combined
foreach($arrays as $nodes) {
    //go through each node of the array
    foreach($nodes as $node) {
        //make sure the node actually has the key we need
        if (isset($node[$key])) {
            //initialize the answer to a new node(array with key, data)
            $ansKey = $node[$key];
            if (!isset($ans[$node[$key]])) {
                $ans[$ansKey] = array();
                $ans[$ansKey][$key] = $node[$key];
                $ans[$ansKey][$data] = 0;
            }
            //make sure the node actually has the data we need
            if (isset($node[$data])) {
                //combined the data
                $ans[$ansKey][$data] += $node[$data];
            }
        }
    }
}
//we only care about the nodes, not the ansKeys we used to get there
return array_values($ans);
}
```

In your example you would call `combine(array($rock, $foo, $bar), "status", "sum")`

This function should be `O(n)` where `n` is the number of nodes. Each node is processed exactly once and because php arrays have a lookup of O(1) we lose no time searching for previous values because all lookups are done on array indexes and not array values.

When I ran the function with your data it returned -

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [status] => 0
        [sum] => 1253
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [status] => 1
        [sum] => 2534
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [status] => 2
        [sum] => 1434
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [status] => 3
        [sum] => 2468
    )

)
```

Comment: @RyanVincent - I added in the results (I did have a small syntax error that I fixed too).

Comment: So, instead of giving first parameter as 'n' number of arrays, can't we merge them first and do the comparison in just a single loop?

Comment: @phantomphoenix, you absolutely could combine the arrays and only have 1 foreach loop on that merged array. I wanted the function signature to take an arbitrary number of arrays to make it easier to use. Additionally, you could also combine the arrays as the first step of the function and keep the function signature the same. This would also eliminate the first foreach loop. All three solutions (the current one, combining the arrays before the function, combining the arrays in the function) will still be O(n) on the total number of nodes.

Comment: Okay, I got it. I was worried and confused because the data set is too large. Anyway, thanks a lot.